# Python3.4 - math with index numbers

Tags: python, math

My objective was to use the index of a list to do addition/subtraction with. Where by I turned the even index positive, and the odd index negative.

EX1: 1234508 Should be answered by a 0: 1-2+3-4+5-0+8 = 11, then the while loops it again and I get 1-2+1 = 0
Ex2: 12345   Should be answered by a 3: 1-2+3-5 = 3, so it shouldn't go through the loop again.
Ex3: 121     Should be answered by a 0: 1-2+1 = 0, so it shouldn't go throught he loop again.

```
def main():
    print()
    print("Program to determine if a number is evenly\ndivisible by 11")
    print()
    indexed = input("Enter a number: ",)

    total = 0
    num = 0
    while num >= 10:    
        for item in indexed:
            if num %2 == 0:
                total = total + int(item) 
            else:                      
                total = total - int(item) 
            num = num + 1

    print(total)

main()
```

Note that this print statement above is a place holder for a if statement which is inactive on my code, but was printing as large bold print here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a string `st` whose characters are all digits, and that you want to have the sum of these digits. You then define the following function

```
def sd(st):
    return sum(int(d) for d in st)
```

that we can test in the interpreter

```
In [30]: sd('10101010101010101010')
Out[30]: 10

In [31]: sd('101010101010101010101')
Out[31]: 11
```

---

What you really want is to sum the odd digits and subtract the even ones, but this is equivalent to sum the odds, sum separately the evens and then take the difference, isn't it? so what you want is

```
step_1 = sd(odds(st)) - sd(evens(st))
```

How can you separate the odd digits from the even ones? Ah! no need for a function, we can use slices

```
step_2 = sd(st[::2]) - sd(st[1::2])
```

Now we want to test the slices in the interpreter

```
In [32]: '101010101010101010101'[::2]
Out[32]: '11111111111'

In [33]: '101010101010101010101'[1::2]
Out[33]: '0000000000'
```

But `step_2` could be a negative number, that I don't want to manage... I'd rather use the `abs` builtin

```
step_3 = abs(sd(st[::2]) - sd(st[1::2]))
```

and this is exactly what you were looking for.

---

Eventually we can put all the above together, but we may need to iterate until the difference is less than `11` --- we'll use an infinite loop and a `break` statement to exit the loop when we'll have found the answer

```
def sd(st):
    return sum(int(d) for d in st)

number = input('Give me a number: ')

trial = number
while True:
    n = abs(sd(trial[::2]) - sd(trial[1::2]))
    if n < 11: break
    trial = str(n)

if n > 0:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code achieves the desired outcome, but I now must study it as to understand it. I thank you very much for the help you have provided.

In the last 15 hours, my code had changed a bit, but so did the single issue I now have to work out. Maybe after studying your code, I can achieve the answer to my own.

Comment: Hi Robert, should you need a more detailed explanation of something in my code just ask, if I'm around I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the offer of additional help in understanding your code. I am a student in computer programing and my instructor desires us to do the problem with the code starting with a def main(): and ending with a main()

Further, for this project, he mandates that we learn how to use the while function as written. while num >= 10:

On a side note, I did figure out how to reduce a step or two of your code, by removing trial = number and placing the initial variable in which the input was stored where trial was placed. So I learned somethings, and had to look up other things. I thank you.

Comment: You save a line of code but you lose the value of the input, because you overwrite `number` during the loop.  What if you want to eventually output a message like 'The number ... is/is not divisible by 11'? you can circumvent the problem but using an auxiliary variable is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly do you want to do with this?

```
evenindex = evenindex int(item)
```

"list" is a type, means the list type in python, so it cannot be the name of a variable. Furthermore, you have not defined this variable in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your timely answer. The short answer is that I am illiterate when it comes to programing, my code has changed for the better, but I have run into another issue.

Comment: Please rate me well if I helped you. I'm banned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to the question I asked above. As such, my answer here is in the event anyone stumbles upon my above question.

def main():
    indexed = input("Enter a number: ",)

```
total = 0
num = 0
while num <= 10:
    for item in indexed:
        if num %2 == 0:
            total = abs(total + int(item)) 
        else:                      
            total = abs(total - int(item))
        num = num + 1

if total == 0:
    print(indexed, "is evenly divisible by 11 \ncheck since", indexed, "modulus 11 is", int(indexed) % 11)      
else:
    print(indexed, "is not evenly divisible by 11 \ncheck since", indexed, "modulus 11 is", int(indexed) % 11)

input()
```

main()